# How can I save an object to a file?

Tags: ruby, json, serialization, marshalling, yaml

I would like to save an object to a file, and then read it from the file easily. As a simple example, lets say I have the following 3d array:

```
m = [[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Is there an easy Ruby API that I can use to achieve this without programming a parser to interpret the data from the file? In the example I give it is easy, but as the objects become more complicated, it gets annoying to make objects persistent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See Marshal: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html

-or-

YAML: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html

Comment: Marshal is not a good tool for persistence, the format depends on the Ruby version and there's no way to decode older Marshal formats in new Rubies. ["In normal use, marshaling can only load data written with the same major version number and an equal or lower minor version number."](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html).

Answer (score 53):

You need to serialize the objects before you could save them to a file and deserialize them to retrieve them back. As mentioned by Cory, 2 standard serialization libraries are widely used, [`Marshal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html) and [`YAML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html).

Both `Marshal` and `YAML` use the methods `dump` and `load` for serializing and deserializing respectively.

Here is how you could use them:

```
m = [
     [
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]
     ],
     [
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]
     ]
    ]

# Quick way of opening the file, writing it and closing it
File.open('/path/to/yaml.dump', 'w') { |f| f.write(YAML.dump(m)) }
File.open('/path/to/marshal.dump', 'wb') { |f| f.write(Marshal.dump(m)) }

# Now to read from file and de-serialize it:
YAML.load(File.read('/path/to/yaml.dump'))
Marshal.load(File.read('/path/to/marshal.dump'))
```

You need to be careful about the file size and other quirks associated with File reading / writing.

More info, can of course be found in the API documentation.

Comment: Don't have enough privilege to edit your answer and add this to it. :-)

Comment: @Swanand actually for me in Ruby 2.0.0 this doesn't work, and should rather be `File.open('/path/to/file.extension', 'wb') {|f| f.write(Marsshal.dump(m)) }` and `File.open('/path/to/file.extension', 'rb') {|f| m = Marshal::load(f)}` (Making it binary reading&writing, this may have been standard back then, otherwise there is an ASCI-8BIT to UTF8-Conversion error popping up) - and if m is an object of a manually defined class, I have to make sure this class is loaded before Marshall::load works (otherwise you get the class/modul unknown error)

Comment: @YoLudke - I think the class / module loading before `Marshal#load` is a given, but you are right to mention it explicitly. Also, this code was written in 1.8.7 (works for 1.9.3 too), but thanks for pointing out about 2.0.0. I'll give it a shot and update the answer.

Comment: Marshal is not a good tool for persistence, the format depends on the Ruby version and there's no way to decode older Marshal formats in new Rubies. ["In normal use, marshaling can only load data written with the same major version number and an equal or lower minor version number."](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html).

Comment: @muistooshort Agreed.

Comment: Don't forget to add ```require 'yaml'```.

Answer (score 3):

YAML and Marshal are the most obvious answers, but depending on what you're planning to do with the data, [sqlite3](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/) may be a useful option too.

```
require 'sqlite3'

m = [[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]]

db=SQLite3::Database.new("demo.out")
db.execute("create table data (x,y,z,value)")
inserter=db.prepare("insert into data (x,y,z,value) values (?,?,?,?)")
m.each_with_index do |twod,z|
  twod.each_with_index do |row,y|
    row.each_with_index do |val,x|
      inserter.execute(x,y,z,val)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend, there are many datatype inconsistencies with `sqlite3` because it infers type from data instead of using a rigid type system: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html