# Can we store multiple objects in file?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am already familiar with [How can I save an object to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310217/how-can-i-save-an-object-to-a-file)

But what if we have to store multiple objects (say hashes) to a file.

I tried appending `YAML.dump(hash)` to a file from various locations in my code. But the difficult part is reading it back. As yaml dump can extend to many lines, do I have to parse the file? Also this will only complicate code. Is there a better way to achieve this?

PS: Same issue will persist with `Marshal.dump`. So I prefer `YAML` as its more human readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`YAML.dump` creates a single Yaml [*document*](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2800132). If you have several Yaml documents together in a file then you have a Yaml [*stream*](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2801681). So when you appended the results from several calls to `YAML.dump` together you would have had a stream.

If you try reading this back using `YAML.load` you will only get the first document. To get all the documents back you can use [`YAML.load_stream`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_stream), which will give you an array with an entry for each of the documents.

An example:

```ruby
f = File.open('data.yml', 'w')

YAML.dump({:foo => 'bar'}, f)

YAML.dump({:baz => 'qux'}, f)

f.close
```

After this `data.yml` will look like this, containing two separate documents:

```yaml
---
:foo: bar
---
:baz: qux
```

You can now read it back like this:

```ruby
all_docs = YAML.load_stream(File.open('data.yml'))
```

Which will give you an array like `[{:foo=>"bar"}, {:baz=>"qux"}]`.

If you don’t want to load all the documents into an array in one go you can pass a block to `load_stream` and handle each document as it is parsed:

```
YAML.load_stream(File.open('data.yml')) do |doc|
  # handle the doc here
end
```

Comment: this is awesome!! I never knew `load_stream` existed. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could manage to save multiple objects by creating a delimiter (something to mark that one object is finished and that you go to the next one). You could then process the file in two steps:

- read the file, splitting it around each delimiter
- use YAML to restore the hashes from each chunk

Now, this would be a bit cumbersome, as there is a much simpler solution. Let's say you have three hash to save:

```
student = { first_name: "John"}
restaurant = { location: "21 Jump Street" }
order = { main_dish: "Happy Meal" }
```

You can simply put them in an array and then dump them:

```
objects = [student, restaurant, order]
dump = YAML.dump(objects)
```

You can restore your objects easily:

```
saved_objects = YAML.load(dump)
saved_student = saved_objects[0]
```

Depending of your objects relationship, you may prefer to use an Hash to save them instead of an array (so that you can name them instead of depending on the order).

Comment: thanks. In my case dumping them in single array is not possible, so I guess using delimiters and parsing the file accordingly, chunk wise is the only option. Something I was trying avoid altogether.. :-/

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "dumping in a single array is not possible"? I'm curious, because I dislike the "delimiters" solution also

Comment: well I am gathering `ObjectSpace` from different files executed in a single thread. So in order to use an array I'll need to define it at the start of the thread, make it global and dump in the end. But the problem is, this array may get exponentially large in size affecting my results.

Comment: Using an array-of-hashes or a hash-of-hashes to store multiple hashes in a single file is more appropriate and standard. If you need persistence that is accessible by multiple threads, consider using a true database. Even SQLite would work.