# How to auto save state of long iteration in ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have a program with a runtime in the order of weeks with a structure like this:

```
(1..1000).each do |number|
  ('a'..'z').each do |letter|
    %w(alpha beta omega whatever foo bar).each do |word|
      do_long_running_calculation(number,letter,word)
    end
  end
end
```

Since the machine running the program may have a sudden unexpected halt, I'd like to save the index that it was on for each array to a file, such that it can re-start from where it left off instead of starting from the beginning in case of a sudden program abort.

Ultimately if this doesn't yet exist as a library (or easy solution that has evaded me), I'm going to make it myself and post it as an answer, but I would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel

Comment: Try using a cache layer in between. Something like redis/memcache would help

Comment: Saving is easy. Correctly _resuming_ - that's the hard part.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create a library to deal with the general case. Rather, I think you'd need a program that would execute Ruby itself in such a way that it could take a snapshot and resume from a snapshot. That would be a big job and version-specific, and might convert your weeks to months or years.

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff, I don't understand how that would help. Specifically, how would you resume calculations?

Comment: @Cary i would have saved the variable and index in redis..whenever the loop starts..and then if it breaks..I pick the last value from the redis and start from there

Comment: Amit, for the example given, which has three nested loops, suppose you save at `[579, 'r', 'omega']`. How are you going to "start from there"? As  @Sergio says, the hard part is not saving, but resuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to deal with your specific example, which could be generalized.

First, two helpers:

```
class Range
  def size # overwrite
    case first
    when Fixnum
      last - first + 1
    when String
      last.ord - first.ord + 1
    end
  end

  def [](offset)
    case first
    when Fixnum
      first + offset
    when String
      (first.ord + offset).chr
    end
  end
end
```

For example:

```
(1..10).size    #=> 10 
('a'..'z').size #=> 26 
(1..10)[4]      #=> 5 
('a'..'z')[4]   #=> "e"
```

For the example:

```
loops = [(1..1000), ('a'..'z'), %w(alpha beta omega whatever foo bar)]
loop_sizes = loops.map(&:size)
  #=> [1000, 26, 6]
prod = 1
tot_nbr_loops, *prod_loop_sizes = (loop_sizes + [1]).reverse.
  map { |n| prod = n*prod }.reverse
  #=> [156000, 156, 6, 1] 
tot_nbr_loops
  #=> 156000 
prod_loop_sizes
  #=> [156, 6, 1]
```

Using these objects we can create a method that maps a sequence of integers into the triples that are to be enumerated:

```
def elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, offset)
  loops.zip(prod_loop_sizes).map do |loop, prod|
  div, offset = offset.divmod(prod)
  loop[div]
  end
end
```

Let's try it:

```
elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, 0)      #=> [1, "a", "alpha"] 
elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, 5)      #=> [1, "a", "bar"] 
elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, 6)      #=> [1, "b", "alpha"] 
elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, 155)    #=> [1, "z", "bar"] 
elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, 156)    #=> [2, "a", "alpha"] 
elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, 156)    #=> [2, "a", "alpha"] 
elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, 156)    #=> [2, "a", "alpha"] 
elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, 155999) #=> [1000, "z", "bar"]
```

So now you could write something like this:

```
save_interval = 10_000

total_number_loops.times do |i|
  a,b,c = elements(loops, prod_loop_sizes, i) 
  # perform calculations with a,b,c
  if i % save_interval == 0
     <save the value of i and the current state>
     <delete the previous saved state>
  end
end
```

One easy way to save to (retrieve from) file most Ruby objects is to use the method [Marshal#dump](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) ([Marshal#load](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load)). (Note the Marshal file format is not guaranteed to remain the same from one Ruby version to the next.)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby provide us the trap method to handle the OS generated SIGNALS. When the system shutdown, then it send the SIGTERM signal. So all we need to handle that signal.

```
trap("TERM") do
  write_data_to_file
end

def write_data_to_file
  # code to save data in the file,
end
```

To read/write from file, cool answer is here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4310299/4136098

Comment: Yes, I meant "data".It can be anything you want to save, so that you can resume your process

Comment: Sorry its is typo mistake. It was "write_data_to_file". I will update answer as well

Comment: This doesn't deal with a "sudden, unexpected halt", where no signal is sent. You could periodically ",`write_data_to_file`", but the OP wants to know how calculations would be resumed after reading that file.